# Using chain rule for derivative of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I've been [trying to learn more about the chain rule of a multivariable function](https://mathinsight.org/chain_rule_multivariable_special_cases), but I'm a bit confused on a special case I've encountered. I'm given a single valued function

$\displaystyle f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$

evaluated at $x_3 = g(x_1,x_2)$, which is also a single valved function. Note that $x_n$ are all scalars. I think I would summarize the functions as $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I'm going to represent the function composition as

$\displaystyle h(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2)) \equiv (f \circ g)(x_1,x_2)$

(EDIT: The equivalence above is wrong...see answer/comments)

in which $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I'm told to find the derivative of $h$ with respect to $x_2$. However, I want to write down the general expression for the derivative. Following the link above (and material within), I can use the so called derivative operator $\textbf{D}$ and write

$\displaystyle \textbf{D}h = \textbf{D}f|_{x_3=g}\textbf{D}g$

where I've introduced the notation $|_{x_3=g}$ to denote "is evaluated at $x_3 = g(x_1,x_2)$" and dropped the other function variables for clarity. What I don't follow is how to write this in terms of vector/matrix products. In some of the [linked material](https://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix), it says the derivative of a scalar valued function is expressed as a $1 \times n$ row vector. Therefore,

$\displaystyle \textbf{D}h = \left[ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1} \quad \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}\right]$

$\displaystyle \textbf{D}f|_{x_3=g} = \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}|_{x_3=g} \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}|_{x_3=g} \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=g} \right]$

$\displaystyle \textbf{D}g = \left[ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}\right]$

I know the answer, specific to the question: "find the derivative of $h$ with respect to $x_2$" is

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}|_{x_3=g} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}|_{x_3=g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}$

so, my question is not about the answer. I'm trying to see how I would arrive at that using vector/matrix products? Specifically, the form "$\displaystyle \textbf{D}h = \textbf{D}f|_{x_3=g}\textbf{D}g$" is easy to remember (from single variable days), and if I can understand how to use it for all special cases, that would be helpful (using the case presented here to showcase).

Comment: Your equation $h = f\circ g$ is just wrong. However, Literally showed you the correct composition.

Comment: Yes, you're right...instead of correcting the question, I just pointed to the answer/comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $G(x,y)=(x,y,g(x,y))$ and consider $f \circ G=f(x,y,g(x,y))$.  Now we have

$DG= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
g_x & g_y 
\end{bmatrix}
$
and $Df=[f_x, f_y, f_z]$.  Now $Df \circ DG = [f_x + f_z g_x , f_y+f_z g_y]$ and we get what you have, $h_y=f_y+f_z g_y$

The problem was that you didn't set up the $G$ correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify..."G" here is a vector-valued multivariable function? So the composition can also be expressed as "f(G)" (i.e. f(G) = f(x,y,g(x,y)) )? Lastly, what you've shown here for $\textbf{D}f \circ \textbf{D}G$ is 3 components in brackets, with the last being zero. Therefore, is it OK that I have defined "h" as "$h(x_1,x_2)$" (i.e. 2d vs 3d domain)? Even though you've shown the terms in brackets, is it understood that those terms are summed to produce a scalar value ("h" is scalar valued function) or do I have to emphasize that in some way?

Comment: The terms in the brackets are the partials oh h as per the chain rule, i.e. we have $[h_x, h_y, h_z]$.  The problem is that f takes values in $R^3$ so you need G to also take values in $R^3$

Comment: Basically, this $ h(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2)) \equiv (f \circ g)(x_1,x_2)$ should be replaced with $h(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f(G(x_1,x_2,x_3)) \equiv (f \circ G)(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, where $G(x_1,x_2,x_3) = <x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2)>$ (where < > denotes a vector)?

Comment: $f \circ g$ doesn't make sense because g is a real number, not a vector.  i.e. $g: R^2 \to R$.  and $G : R^2 \to R^3$.

Comment: Ahh....I think I see now. This is wrong $f(x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2)) \equiv (f \circ g)(x_1,x_2)$. The composition, as I wrote, is $(f \circ g)(x_1,x_2) \equiv f(g(x_1,x_2))$, which is not how $f$ is defined (i.e. takes $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the domain).

Comment: As you've stated, $G:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, which makes sense. It takes the input "$(x_1,x_2)$" and produces the vector-valued output "<$x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2)$>", which then feeds into "f". I guess the only thing that isn't clear to me now is, you orginally said "G(x,y,z) = <x,y,g(x,y)>" which is $G:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. This clearly made $\textbf{D}G$ work out to a nice $3 \times 3$ matrix. If the domain of "G" were restricted to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (e.g. G(x,y)), then $\textbf{D}G$ would be a  $3 \times 2$, where the "3" is due to output dim and "2" to input dim?

Comment: No, I made a typo.  I meant $G(x,y)$.  I've edited it now.